# are first order function and first class functions same in javascript..?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions, first-class-functions

what are first class functions and first order functions..?  Both are same or not..? Is there any similarities/difference between first order and first class functions in javascript.

I tried to get an answer but didn't get a well-explained one. please help me..
Many sites only explain what is first-class function, not first-order functions. If both are the same, they don't mention it.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, a first-order function is a function that is **not** a higher-order function.

A higher-order function is a function that takes one or more functions as arguments, or returns a function as its result.

First-class functions are functions that can be used like any other value, such as being assigned to a variable, passed as an argument to a function or returned as a result from a function.

In JavaScript, **all functions are first-class functions**, so a first-order function is also a first-class function.